# How to get compute unit ID at runtime in OpenCL?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu

Is there a way to get the compute unit ID a work group is running on during runtime? I know that CUDA has some assembly code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to get the compute unit's ID.  Your code should use the work group ID instead.  What are you trying to achieve?

I am a little surprised that CUDA supports this, please tell me which assembly code instruction does this.